# cannot seem to run jar file

Tags: java, jar, classpath

How do i set the classpath in a unix environment using tsch script. I try to set the path as follows but it gives me errors

setenv CLASSPATH $CLASSPATH : path but it doens't work saying -Bad : modifier in $(/). i dont understand why i cannot set this class path. Due to this i cannot run my .jar executable as i want to and i am running out of time. When i try to run the .jar file it give s me the following error

new error...it shows this when i try to run the jar file   along with the path to where my jar file is actually located and this is the error i receive

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.Error: Properties init: Could not determine current working directory.
    at java.lang.System.initProperties(Native Method)
    at java.lang.System.initializeSystemClass(System.java:1070)
```

Comment: `setenv CLASSPATH /path/to/jar/file:/another/path` or `java -classpath /java/MyClasses/myclasses.jar utility.myapp.Cool`

Comment: make sure you compile with `javac -classpath /java/MyClasses/myclass.jar utility.myapp.Cool.java` as well

Comment: @user1332681 - did you find the problem?  If not please cut/paste 1) output of "echo $CLASSPATH", 2) the exact command and error of your "setenv" command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there are at least two issues here:

> 1) setenv CLASSPATH $CLASSPATH : path but it doens't work saying -Bad
>   : modifier in $(/).

This sounds like a "tsch" error calling "setenv" with a bad value for "$CLASSPATH".  Take a look at your $CLASSPATH (or post it here): the problem should be apparent.

> 2) Error occurred during initialization of VM

This is because you don't *have* a classpath yet.  But fixing your "setenv()" syntax might not necessarily fix the "java init" problem - we'll just have to take it one step at a time.

Please post the value of `echo $CLASSPATH`, the value *before* you try "setenv".  That should help us fix problem 1)

Answer (score 0):

The classpath should be set in the manifest file inside the jar. If not, you might try unpacking the jar and running it with the `java -cp *myClassPath* *myMainClass*` command.

You can set the classpath with environment variables - but why bother? If you run from a script anyways, I figure specifying the `-cp` option is much less error-prone.