# error trying to run jar file

Tags: jar

i have tried to get help me nobody seems to understand my problem. I created a project in netbeans and it produces a jar file when i compiled it. It runs just fine on through the IDE but when i try to launch it from the command prompt it simply does not do anything. It just moves the cursor to the next line for another command? when i echo my classpath this is the result i get

```
/opt/netbeans-7.1.2/ide/modules/ext/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar:/h/USERS/local/pagola/NetBeansProjects/mylib/dist/mylib.jar:/h/USERS/local/pagola/NetBeansProjects/EOPPrototype/build/classes
```

i have added the classpath which contains everything that is within the jar. My manifest file contains the main class(entry point) and this is what it looks like

```
    Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.6.0_22-b04 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Class-Path: lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar lib/mylib.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: eopprototype.EOPPrototype
```

and so i cant figure out what i am doing wrong? do i need to add anything to my PATH variable (maybe the java jdk bin stuff) is it not able to locate the java command because it doe not know where to look for that executable?

NOTE: i did not setenv my PATH and LIBRARY PATH -do i need to do this ? this is a c style shell script

Comment: You already asked this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005322/cannot-seem-to-run-jar-file).  Please don't say "nobody seems to understand my problem".  Please respond as requested in your previous post, and I'm sure the problem can be easily resolved.  Generally, the syntax of your script should be something like `java -cp myjar.jar com.mypackage.MyClass`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this first**

If your Manifest does not end with a newline it maybe ignored. See [manifest requires a newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169188/why-is-jar-ignoring-my-manifest)

**Otherwise I have to make assumptions**

You don't need `lib/mylib.jar` in your manifest if that JAR file contains `EOPPrototype` with a `public static void main(String[] args)` method that you wish to execute. So remove it so it only lists `mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar`. Your manifest will then look like this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.6.0_22-b04 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Class-Path: lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: eopprototype.EOPPrototype
```

Then assuming all your code is in mylib.jar and the only other dependant jar is mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar, create a directory structure like this

```
/h/USERS/temp/mylib.jar
/h/USERS/temp/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar
```

Then execute like this

```
cd /h/USERS/temp

java -cp .:mylib.jar eopprototype.EOPPrototype
```